# Get position of an ID based on MySQL COUNT result

Tags: php, mysql, count

I am not even sure if this has been answered because I don't even know how to coin the problem. But here is what am trying to do.

I am using COUNT() to create a tabular representation of a data from top to bottom for a 30 day period.

```
 SELECT id FROM table WHERE col = '123' AND date >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE)-1 DAY) AND date <=  LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) GROUP BY id ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC
```

And I get the result with the most at the top

```
id  | col
==========
id3 | 123
id5 | 123
id2 | 123
id4 | 123
id8 | 123
id5 | 123
id1 | 123
id9 | 123
id7 | 123
```

This works fine for a tabular view and I can use ol to create a numbering system from 1 - 10. My issue is, I want to be able to tell the position of any given id. Eg. if I want to get the position of id9 in this count result i.e. 8, how do I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using MySQL v8.0 or higher you can use [the `RANK` function](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-rank-function/):

```
SELECT COUNT(*), RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC) AS r FROM table GROUP BY id ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC;
```

For previous version of mysql, you need to create the variable your self:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), @rank := @rank + 1 AS r FROM table, (SELECT @rank := 0) temp ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC;
```

Note `SELECT @rank := 0` initiate the variable.

Updated:

To select a specific `id` and it's rank, you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id, COUNT(*), RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC) AS r FROM table GROUP BY id ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC
    ) ranked WHERE id = ?;
```

Comment: Thanks Amir! I tried this but it's giving me the total number of rows for that id, not the position of the id. I am not sure am retrieving the result the right way. How do I retrieve the position? I usually would do something like $count = $db['COUNT(*)']; echo $count;

Comment: You need to get the rank: $rank = $db['r']

Comment: Hi Amir, so I did that but no matter the id I use, the row number is 1. I think it's counting the number of ids that have that result hence 1. Instead of giving me the position of that id in the count result

Comment: @jay can you confirm your MySQL version?

Comment: @JaySmoke does updated answer work for you?

Comment: @AmirMB tried it and nope, it didn't work! :( no result is produced. It's null.

Comment: I've edited the question query, can you please take a look and advice acoordingly? Thank you.

Comment: @AmirMB thanx man! I figured it out. It works now.

Comment: @JaySmoke perfect!